# How to import/upload json file to arangoDB with _id?

Tags: arangodb

I want to import my json file to create a collection. From the docs i tried this below,

```
arangoimp --file nodes.json --collection nodes --create-collection true
```

where `nodes.json` is my local file and `nodes` is my collection.
I can successfully done this process without any trouble. But It arangoDB creates it's `_id` by itself. I want to skip this process. i.e., I want to specify the `_id` value to my document. How to do this?

I tried to create another one field with the name `_id`. But it didn't create anything(I think `_id` is reserved word). How to upload a file with specifying `_id` is  `arangoimp`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `_id` is a combination of the collection name and `_key` and will be generated during import.

Use `_key` in your json / json lines import file instead:

```
{ "_key": "IDDQD", "value": "James"}
{ "_key": "IDBEHOLDI", "value": 42}
```

Complete documentation, also how to specify an already existing ID as `_key` (CSV import) could be found in the [arangoimp documentation](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/Manual/Programs/Arangoimport/ExamplesJson.html).

Answer (score 1):

The id field should normally be: collectionName + "\" + _key. So if you provide the _key, the _id would be created automatically.

If you want the key and the your "id" field to be different, I would recommend importing the data into an  "id" field and let Arango just generate the _id normally for its internal use.